# How to deactivate Pre-registration campaign for app in Google Play Developer Console

Tags: google-play, google-play-console, google-developers-console

i recently activated the Pre-registration campaign for my app in play console for all countries, and now that i want to remove it, i am unable to do so because i cant find any option for removing it. Currently the app is published in Closed testing, Open testing and Internal testing. App is not publushed in production yet.

Any hep would be appreciated. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

select Release in google play consle then production in app you wont to update then after you upload release go to countries select countries you chose in Pre-registration and its will automatically update.